# How does the intensity of scattered light depend on the intensity of incident light?

Tags: optics, scattering

Let's say I shine an infrared laser beam on a particle in the first scenario, and white light or visible light on the same particle, in the second scenario. The particle scatters the light rays in both cases. In which case will the intensity of these scattered light rays be greater? Since we are using a laser in the first case which is a coherent and intense source of light, will the scattered light rays also be more intense than what you would get when the same particle scatters visible light? Please clarify.

Comment: See "Rayleigh scattering"

Comment: Particles can be moddelled as harmonic osscilators when incoming light hits it. When $\omega >> \omega_{0}$ then $ P \propto f ^4$ the power radiated for blue light is greater than any other colours, hence the sky is blue

Comment: Your title references intensity, but question references frequency. High frequency light in total may have less energy than low frequency. However each photon will carry more energy for high frequency

Comment: @jensenpaull Please convert your comments to an answer. See [this guidance about using comments for "brief" answers](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/44126) (tldr: don't).